# Footer becomes sticky after scrolling up inside a scroll snap container

Tags: html, css, snap

I'm creating a website which contains sections with a scroll snap container. Each section should take 100% of the screen (100vh). Unfortunately, when I scroll all the way down to the footer and scroll up again, the footer becomes sticky in Google Chrome (haven't tested any other browsers yet)

What I want to achieve: The footer should not become sticky. The snapping behaviour can be fully ignored for the footer.

You can see the the behaviour in the link below. Just scroll all the way down to the footer and scroll up again. The footer will become sticky... I have tried to set `position: absolute` to the footer but nothing really worked.

Thank you guys!

```css
main {
    croll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
    Footer
<footer>
```

Comment: You are likely on a Mac. Turn on Always for scrollbars in System Preferences to see what's occurring. Hint: it's the  two scrollbars: https://imgur.com/a/qey36Vb

Comment: It's not sticky, you are scrolling into the `main` element

Comment: @Leland Thank you! I haven't thought about that. This might help me to understand what's going on

Comment: @Brewal ...but why is that? Because I set `main { height: 100vh; }` shouldn't that tell the main tag to take up 100% of the screen height?

Comment: @Phillip I tried to fix your code in my answer. Hope I understood what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` element is set to `height` 100vh and both of your sections are set to `height` 100vh.

You have `overflow-y: scroll;` on your main. So basically, when you scroll down on your page, you scroll on the `main` element that have a content of 2x the height of your screen.

When you reach the down of the `main`, you start to scroll down the entire page. So you start to see the footer.

When you scroll up, you might be scrolling into the `main` element again. So the footer just "stays" there because you are not scrolling the page.

I think you can get the desired behavior by removing `overflow-y` and `height` on the `main` element

```css
main {
    croll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
    Footer
<footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! This isn't really what I want. I want the sections to snap. But I just saw that it didn't work in my initial code snippet. I think I found a solution, see my answer. It's going to be hard to implement this on my website but it works the way I want it to work. Thanks for pointing out that I was scrolling inside two different elements, that really helped me!

Comment: Indeed, I missed the snap rule ! You can go with your solution indeed ! Or wrap `main` and `footer` inside another div i.e.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I solved my problem.

```css
body {
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

main {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}

footer {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
    <section>
      Section
    </section>
    <footer>
      Footer
    <footer>
</main>
```